# new flutter sdk version error - Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'

Tags: flutter, dart

The project was working but after I used flutter sdk 3.7.8 then flutter sdk 3.7.9 and both versions give me this error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\mobiledev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 912
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
> > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [C:\mobiledev\apps\projectb\projectb\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug]

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

flutter version
flutter sdk version 3.7.9

pubspec.ymal
environment:
sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'

build.gradle
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'